# How to make a generic repeat, try, except and raise in python that can wrap arbitrary code blocks

Tags: python

I have a code that tries a block of code, if error happens, retry up to a max count.

The structure is re-used many times.

Something looks like this:

```py
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30

result = None

max_loop = 3
interval = 1

for i in range(max_loop):
    try:
        # these are generic statements
        statement_1(a)
        statement_2(b)
        # ...
        result = statement_3(c)        
        break
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'retry {i}')
        logging.error(e)
        time.sleep(interval)
raise Exception(f'Failed after {max_loop} retries')
```

Is there a way to create a wrap/decorator/contextmanager, etc of the `for: try: ... except:raise` so I can reuse the structure? Something similar to in-line block, or anonymous function in other languages?

I cannot create a function because the `try:` block can contain any statements, and use any variables. Ideally, the structure should be able to take arbitrary code block.

example:

```py
repeat_try_and_raise:
    statement_1(a)
    statement_2(b)
    # ...
    result = statement_3(c) 

# ...

repeat_try_and_raise:
    statement_4(a)
    statement_5(b)
    # ...
    statement_6(c)
```

EDIT

#### Reasons I don't want to use a function to wrap the statements

1. I am lazy, don't want to create a function for a single use every time I reuse the work flow.
2. The function will have its own scope which will make accessing variables in my code not straightforward

Comment: Why do you need to insert an arbitrary number of statements, and not just encapsulate them in a single function call? If you have some procedure that uses `statement_1(a)`, `statement_2(b)`, etc., and a final result is calculated using `statement_3(c)`... just put them in a function, and decorate that function with your try/catch/retry logic.

Comment: You say you cannot do this, but it's not clear at all *why* you can't do this.

Comment: @ddejohn, yes I can do that but want to find a better way to avoid create functions every time I want to use it.

Comment: Your question is, essentially, two questions: "How do I write a generic repeat/try/catch structure that can be used on arbitrary code", which can be answered by asking "how do I wrap arbitrary code?". The answers are "with decorators" and "by wrapping your arbitrary code inside function definitions", respectively. Anything else, as far as I can see, would be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've never messed around with implementing my own context managers, but I could see something like that working. Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @ddejohn Alright, posted an apparently working version now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea with a context manager:

```
a = 10
result = None
max_loop = 2
interval = 0.1

for attempt in repeat_try_and_raise(max_loop, interval):
    with attempt:
        a += 1
        result = 0/0 if a < 13 else 42

print(f'Success with {result=}')
```

Output for `max_loop = 2`:

```
ERROR:root:retry 0
ERROR:root:division by zero
ERROR:root:retry 1
ERROR:root:division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 25, in <module>
    for attempt in repeat_try_and_raise(max_loop, interval):
  File ".code.tio", line 18, in repeat_try_and_raise
    raise Exception(f'Failed after {max_loop} retries')
Exception: Failed after 2 retries
```

Output for `max_loop = 3`:

```
ERROR:root:retry 0
ERROR:root:division by zero
ERROR:root:retry 1
ERROR:root:division by zero
Success with result=42
```

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVI9T8MwEN39K25rIqqQUgZU0YEBRhbYLZNegoUTWxcHElX97eHc5qNUMODJvnv37t47u86/22p956jvdekseTC2KHRVLMHrEoXYYQ6EDpWXnjqpqp0kpWuMStVKY61bgq480qcy8UYAn8youoYH77F0/hQKJxBJiQErZVSjyeM5GY7jskt0q/0AXgK2mfSdw9ON@zV89aQyfFPZxwVZKEkQtjP2R5rQN1TBKw3x3BJoFgKkqmLWdkaqTnqYcVAWxVOu02h2I2KK6nwM8SC6hmdb4eaXKabQ4HyCRJaifMFp6mCvD4v4D8zEPwPC1pLaILpo2ssxedwaPLYZOq9txfxPShvkuXOGwX7UfAhjkcaauwrFelepIKwbE7QHDWJE8nstxib8SJOVEMHJ0avg57@@zpf272P1mfVwxVOI2bVhmPQ6PZoM97BaAxqWd3sjhCNmZXkvTZYh/8Qj6f5UtWUv@/4b)):

```
import logging, time

def repeat_try_and_raise(max_loop, interval):
    class Attempt:
        def __enter__(self):
            pass
        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
            self.e = exc_value
            return True
    for i in range(max_loop):
        attempt = Attempt()
        yield attempt
        if attempt.e is None:
            return
        logging.error(f'retry {i}')
        logging.error(attempt.e)
        time.sleep(interval)
    raise Exception(f'Failed after {max_loop} retries')

a = 10
result = None
max_loop = 3
interval = 0.1

for attempt in repeat_try_and_raise(max_loop, interval):
    with attempt:
        a += 1
        result = 0/0 if a < 13 else 42

print(f'Success with {result=}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you may find just packing all of 'em into another function is what you're after

```py
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3

def function_collection(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    fn1(arg1)
    fn2(arg2)
    fn3(arg3)

def wrapper(target, target_kwargs, max_attempts=MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    assert max_attempts >= 2
    for attempt in range(max_attempts):
        try:
            return target(**fn_kwargs)
        except SubClassException:
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            LOGGER.warning(f"something unexpected went wrong: {repr(ex)}")
    raise OSError(f"no run of target succeeded after {max_attempts} attempts")

wrapper(function_collection, {"arg1": 10, "arg2": 20, "arg3": 30})
```

Comment: That is the only way?

Comment: oh, there's an endless way to do different things in Python, but practically, it's extremely likely that doing this is an anti-pattern to begin with (ie. why is the Exception occurring? can it be remediated the first time? is this really covering up a race?) .. [**@ddejonh**'s answer may be what you're after in the interim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71756662/4541045)!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need to "inject" arbitrary code statements into the `try` block. If you have procedures that are made up of arbitrary statements, wrap the procedures up in a function definition, and decorate the function:

```py
import time
import logging


def retry(*, max_retries: int, sleep_interval: int):
    def retry_wrapper(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(max_retries):
                try:
                    logging.info(f"Trying function {f.__name__}")
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as error:
                    logging.info(f"retry {i}")
                    logging.error(error)
                    time.sleep(sleep_interval)
            raise Exception(f"Failed after {max_retries} tries")
        return wrapped
    return retry_wrapper


@retry(max_retries=6, sleep_interval=2)
def procedure_1(*args, **kwargs):
    # statement 1
    # statement 2
    # statement 3
    pass


@retry(max_retries=3, sleep_interval=1)
def procedure_2(*args, **kwargs):
    # statement 4
    # statement 5
    # statement 6
    pass
```

If you trust the source of these arbitrary code statements, you could pass them as strings and use `eval()` but again, I cannot imagine a scenario where wrapping your procedures into a function isn't more appropriate.

Here's one way you might do this, using the same decorator as above:

```py
@retry(max_retries=3, sleep_interval=1)
def arbitrary_code_runner(*statements):
    for statement in statements:
        eval(statement)
```

Output:

```py
In [5]: arbitrary_code_runner("print('hello world')", "print(sum(x**2 for x in range(10)))", "print('I am arbitrary code, I am potentially dangerous')")
Trying function arbitrary_code_runner
hello world
285
I am arbitrary code, I am potentially dangerous
```

The problem with this approach is that you cannot save the results of each statement. If your code statements are mutators then this is not a problem, but if any of your arbitrary statements rely on the results of other statements, you'll have to nest the function calls (like how I used `print(sum(...`.

Another technique would be to use anonymous and/or named functions to store your arbitrary statements, and then run each statement one at a time:

```py
@retry(max_retries=3, sleep_interval=1)
def arbitrary_function_runner(*funcs_and_args_and_kwargs):
    for func, args, kwargs in funcs_and_args_and_kwargs:
        print(f"\n  Function {func.__name__} called")
        print(f"    args: {', '.join(map(str, args))}")
        print(f"    kwargs: {', '.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in kwargs.items())}")
        print(f"    result: {func(*args, **kwargs)}")
```

Which you could then call with an arbitrary number of 3-tuples of `(function, args tuple, kwargs dict)`:

```py
def some_named_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return "some named function's results"


arbitrary_function_runner((lambda *args, **kwargs: "".join(kwargs[arg] for arg in args), ("a", "b", "c"), {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C"}),
                          (lambda x: x**2, (3,), {}),
                          (some_named_function, (1, 2, 3), {"kwarg1": 1, "kwarg_2": 2}))
```

Output:

```py
Trying function arbitrary_function_runner

  Function <lambda> called
    args: a, b, c
    kwargs: a: A, b: B, c: C
    result: ABC

  Function <lambda> called
    args: 3
    kwargs:
    result: 9

  Function some_named_function called
    args: 1, 2, 3
    kwargs: kwarg1: 1, kwarg_2: 2
    result: some named function's results
```